# Visual Studio - Text - Wrapping (Call chain, Every Argument ...) - Options

Tags: c#, visual-studio, word-wrap

I use Visual Studio every day.

I use a lot the functionally that beautify and simply the code reading call "Wrapping".

Is there an option or an extension that automatically apply "wrap format preference"?

Sample:

Wrap every argument - from

```
public AvalonViewManager(DockingManager dockingManager, ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope, IEnumerable<IModuleDescriptor> moduleDescriptors)
```

to

```
public AvalonViewManager(DockingManager dockingManager,
                         ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope,
                         IEnumerable<IModuleDescriptor> moduleDescriptors)
```

Wrap call chain - from

```
_viewModelDescriptors = safeModuleDescriptors.SelectMany(m => m.ViewModels).GroupBy(k => k.UniqueId).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Single());
```

to

```
_viewModelDescriptors = safeModuleDescriptors.SelectMany(m => m.ViewModels)
                                             .GroupBy(k => k.UniqueId)
                                             .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Single());
```

Comment: Rider/Resharper can do this. Have not tried to configure it with "pure" VS.

Comment: Chapter ReSharper and check "Long lines" in ReSharper >> Options... >> Language/C# >> Line wrapping and wrapping, set "Right margin (column)" to the desired value (default is 120)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little bit late, but I found this documentation about VS2022 which could help you (or anyone else reading this post).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/reference/wrap-indent-align-refactorings?view=vs-2022

I believe it works if you do not have ReSharper installed.